# Issuing a refund for a Stripe customer with credit balance

Tags: python, stripe-payments

Let's say that I have 3 products:

- Hobbyist - **Free**
- Professional - **15**€/month
- Enterprise - **60**€/month

Let's also say that I subscribe a customer (that is currently subscribed
to the `Hobbyist` product) to the `Enterprise` product. And let's say that I
create an invoice and bill him immediately.

Now let's say that immediately after that I cancel the customer's
subscription to the `Enterprise` product and subscribe him to the `Professional`
product. Canceling the `Enterprise` product will create a credit balance of `60€`
in the customer's account, and subscribing him to the `Professional` product
will create a new invoice for a total of `0€` because Stripe will subtract `15€`
from the customer's balance.

At this point the customer's balance would be `45€`.

Now let's say that I wait exactly 15 days (let's assume that 1 month == 30 days) and I cancel his subscription and then I try to issue a refund.

The refund should be `7.5€` (15 unused days from the `Professional` product) + `45€`
from the credit balance that the customer's account already had.

Here's where my problems begin.

### First problem

If I try to do something like the following:

```
subscription = self.get_subscription("the_customer_ID")

items = []
for item in subscription.get("items").data:
    items.append({
        "id": item.id,
        "plan": item.plan.id,
        "quantity": 0,
    })

prorated_invoice = stripe.Invoice.upcoming(
    customer=customer.id,
    subscription=subscription.id,
    subscription_items=items,
)

prorated_amount = 0
for item in prorated_invoice.lines.data:
    if item.type == "invoiceitem":
        prorated_amount += abs(item.amount) if item.amount < 0 else 0
```

The `prorated_amount` will be `7.5` (actually `750`, because of how Stripe handles numeric values), which means that the `upcoming` method doesn't
take into account the customer's balance. I didn't manage to find a way (via aditional arguments) to get the prorated amount including the customer's balance, but I guess I could just sum it by getting it from `customer.balance`.

Is the correct way of doing it? Or should I be doing it differently?

### Second problem

Running the code from the first problem and then running this:

```
latest_invoice = stripe.Invoice.retrieve(subscription.latest_invoice)
stripe.Refund.create(
    charge=latest_invoice.charge,
    amount=prorated_amount,
)
```

will cause the following error:

`InvalidRequestError: Request req_***********: One of the following params should be provided for this request: payment_intent or charge.`

This occurs because `latest_invoice` points to the second invoice, which has no `charge` or `payment_intent` fields
because the invoice was entirely covered by the customer's balance (going from `Enterprise` to `Professional` means charging `15€` from a balance of `60€`).

What should I do in this scenario? How can I handle that specific case?

Answer (score 1):

**First problem**

When looking at an upcoming invoice, you can check the [`amount_due`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object?lang=node#invoice_object-amount_due) property to see how much the customer will actually have to pay (so it takes into account the customer balance). If that doesn't work for your use case, then you would need to manually get the `customer.balance` and compute things on your end.

**Second problem**

If you invoice has a `0` amount, then there's no PaymentIntent associated with it, so you can't create a refund. A workaround would be to find another PaymentIntent from the same customer, and use that to do a partial refund. To list all PaymentIntent made by a specific customer, [use this](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/list?lang=node).